# Finding and mapping duplicates in a pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, pandas-groupby

I have 2 columns, User_ID and Item_ID. Now I want to make a new column 'Reordered' which will contain values as either 0 or 1. 0 is when a particular user has ordered an item only once, and 1 is when a particular user orders an item more than once. 
I think this can be done by grouping on User_ID and then using apply function to map duplicated items as 1 and non duplicated as 0 but I'm not able to figure out the correct python code for that.
If someone can please help me with this.

Comment: can you atleast share the code you have written so far ?? or problem you are facing

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with parameter `keep=False` for all duplicates - output is `True`s and `False`s. Last convert to `int`s by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Reordered'] = df['User_ID'].duplicated(keep=False).astype(int)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User_ID':list('aaabaccd'),
                   'Item_ID':list('eetyutyu')})

df['Reordered'] = df['User_ID'].duplicated(keep=False).astype(int)
print (df)
  Item_ID User_ID  Reordered
0       e       a          1
1       e       a          1
2       t       a          1
3       y       b          0
4       u       a          1
5       t       c          1
6       y       c          1
7       u       d          0
```

Or maybe need [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for check `duplicates` per each user:

```
df['Reordered'] = df.duplicated(['User_ID','Item_ID'], keep=False).astype(int)
print (df)
  Item_ID User_ID  Reordered
0       e       a          1
1       e       a          1
2       t       a          0
3       y       b          0
4       u       a          0
5       t       c          0
6       y       c          0
7       u       d          0
```

Comment: I think its the second one

Comment: Yeah the second one works perfectly for me. Thanks a lot @jezrael